# java.util.NoSuchElementException on java Map

Tags: java, iterator

I just can't figure out what is the problem, why this code is throwing java.util.NoSuchElementException because there is hasNext before next method called

```
        Map results = getResults();
        if (results != null) 
        {

            Set set = results.entrySet();
            Iterator it = set.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                Iterator jt = ((Collection) entry.getValue()).iterator();
                while (jt.hasNext()) {
                    CustomException e = (CustomException) jt.next();
                    String exp = e.getMessage();
                    exp = (exp == null)?"":exp;
                    if(!"".equals(exp) && !exp.contains("errors"))
                    {
                        setError(exp)
                    }


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please post some more code surrounding this code.

Comment: If you have an IDE with a debugger (like Eclipse), might be helpful to put some breakpoints in and step through the code slowly in debug mode to see where the issue is...

Comment: Having the stack trace of the exception, and the corresponding lines in the code, would help finding where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, getResults calls to private API that returns a Map of CustomException (Errors on a business object) and I just set these in ArrayList with setError method

Comment: @PrinceCharming.. Just a suggestion -> Never use `non-generic` version of generic types, if of course you are not by any chance working below Java 1.5.

Comment: @RohitJain, you can compile code that uses generics using a 1.5 compiler and run it on a 1.4 JRE.

Comment: @Isaac.. Yeah,that of course can be done. But you can't write generics in Version less than 1.5. After compilation, generics are anyways removed.

Comment: @RohitJain, you wrote "working"... I interpreted it as "running". :-) (better be clear)

Comment: @Isaac.. I can't get more clear than this.

Comment: Which line are you getting the exception?